# Unity object keep falling towards y-axies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I placed two objects into an image target (cube and sphere). Both have Rigidbodies and I un-checked Use Gravity for both Rigidbodies. On the image target, I have a script that turns the gravity on once that image target is detected. Also, in my AR camera, I selected my image target to be the center of the world. Both objects (cube and sphere) fall down on top of my image target when that image target is detected (the sphere falls on top of the cube). Now, I want to tilt the cube horizontally and vertically whenever the target image tilts and the sphere need to move around accordingly (on top of my cube). How can I change the gravity of those objects and make them do what I want. Here is my script I place on the image target:

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, 
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            Rigidbody[] rigidBodies = GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();
            foreach (Rigidbody r in rigidBodies)
            {
                r.useGravity = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By having the sphere "move around on top of the cube" do you mean that the sphere is always positioned on top of the cube as the cube rotates underneath it? If so, rigidbody gravity physics are the wrong solution.

Comment: correct. That is what I am looking for. I want my cube to fall on top of my image target and my sphere to fall on top of my cube. Then when I tilt the image target, the cube need to tilt and the sphere should move around on top of the cube. @Draco18s

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].